# List elements that are not in a table without left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I list the products that are in a store.

For example:

| Product | Store |
| --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 1 |
| Product 1 | 2 |
| Product 1 | 3 |

On the other hand, I have a table where all the locales that exist are.

| Store |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

I need to know what products are not in any store.

For example, product 1 is not in store 4.

I am trying to reach these cases through LEFT JOIN, but it has not worked for me.

```
select * from productstore ps
left join stores s on ps.storeid=s.storeid
where prdid='Product 1'
and s.storeid IS NULL
```

The way that I have achieved it is the following:

```
SELECT s.storeid FROM stores s 
WHERE not exists
(select ps.storeid from productstore ps
where s.storeid=ps.storeid
and s.PrdId='Product 1')
```

But this works only when I specify a product.

What would be the best way to get all the products that are not in a store?

Comment: You could use a subquery to find the intersection (find all products that __do__ have a store), then use an EXCEPT clause to select all products EXCEPT those products that match with a store.

Comment: Re-reading your question, you seem to ask for 2 things here: *"I need to know what products are not in any store."* but then you go on to state "*For example, product 1 is not in store 4."* Why would product 1 show, when it's in stores 1-3, it's in 3 stores so it's not *not* in any store. What are you actually after? Products that aren't in any store? Stores that don't provide a specific product? Products that aren't in *every* store? Something else?

Comment: Sorry. 

This was not correctly expressed: 
"I need to know what products are not in any store."

I need stores that don't provide a specific product. 

Following the example, the query should return that product 1 is not offered in store 4.

Comment: I think you should provide more sample data with further products and then show the expected result of your query. It's still unclear what you want to do: List all stores that don't provide all products? Or list all stores that don't provide a specific product? List anything else?

Comment: @ThomA Seems clear to me, OP wants a full cross-product excluding the existing join rows. Perhaps *what products are not in any store* could have been worded better: *what products are not in what stores*

Comment: To me "What products are not in any store" means products that aren't [available] in any [of the] stores; I.e. no stores sell them, @Charlieface .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want the cross-join of all `products` and `stores`, for which there does not exist a link in `productstore`.

```sql
SELECT
  p.productid,
  s.storeid
FROM products p
CROSS JOIN stores s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM productstore ps
    WHERE ps.storeid = s.storeid
      AND ps.procductid = p.productid
);
```

Comment: This returns the desired result! 
I would like to understand its operation a little more in detail and why cross join, could it be?

Comment: You want all products for all stores, but you want to exclude the ones that have links already. The query does exactly what it says on the tin.